# Term for $eSe$ where $S$ is a semigroup and $e \in S$ is an idempotent

Tags: terminology, semigroups, monoid, idempotents

For a (possibly non-unital) ring $R$ and an idempotent $e \in R$, $eRe$ is a unital ring with identity $e$ and is known as a corner ring.

Now, given any semigroup $S$ and any idempotent $e \in S$, $eSe$ is a monoid with identity $e$.

But what is the name for a monoid of the form $eSe$? Is it called a "corner monoid", analogous to "corner ring"?

Comment: I often see the term "local submonoid at $e$" for it. Of course, $eSe$ need not be a submonoid, but it is a monoid, so that's just a sleight of hand.

Answer (score 1):

In [Mathematical Foundations of Automata Theory](https://github.com/MPRI/M2-20-2/blob/master/Mathematical%20Foundations%20of%20Automata%20Theory.pdf) by Jean-´Eric Pin, pp.36

> The semigroup $eSe$ $[eS, Se]$ is called the [left, right ]
> local semigroup associated with $e$.